# Array of structures sorting and swapping

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, search, data-structures

I have an array of structured data that holds line coordinates (P1 and P2) which are Vector2d(OpenTK) type that contain X and Y As Double

```
Public Structure sliced
    Public P1, P2 As Vector2d
    Public ID As Integer
End Structure

Dim slicedPoint(30000) As sliced
```

The array will hold multiple randomly ordered line segment. In order to join each line together, I use a simple algorithm to find each pair of the segments to form a closed contour.

```
For i = 0 To SPcount - 2
     slicedPoint(i).ID = groupID

     'Assign starting Point of the loop
     If initialFlag = False Then          'This is done once
         Pstart = slicedPoint(i).P1
         initialFlag = True
     End If

     If slicedPoint(i).P2 <> Pstart Then
         For k = i + 1 To SPcount - 1
             If slicedPoint(i).P2 = slicedPoint(k).P1 Then
                 'Normal order points
                 bufferPoint = slicedPoint(i + 1)        
                 slicedPoint(i + 1) = slicedPoint(k)     
                 slicedPoint(k) = bufferPoint            
                 Exit For
             End If
             If slicedPoint(i).P2 = slicedPoint(k).P2 Then
                 'Inverted points
                 bufferPoint.P1 = slicedPoint(k).P2
                 bufferPoint.P2 = slicedPoint(k).P1
                 slicedPoint(k) = bufferPoint
                 bufferPoint = slicedPoint(i + 1)
                 slicedPoint(i + 1) = slicedPoint(k)
                 slicedPoint(k) = bufferPoint
                 Exit For
             End If

             If k = SPcount - 1 Then
                 My.Application.Log.WriteEntry("Not Found")
             End If
         Next
    Else
        'Closed Contour found, Increment group count
        groupID += 1            'next group starting point refers here
        Pstart = slicedPoint(i + 1).P1
    End If
Next
```

In the above code, `i` index is the reference, and `k` is the search index. `SPCount` is the maximum count for the available segments. The code searches next pair of line segment by referring to `slicedPoint(i).P2`. If `slicedPoint(i).P2` is equal to `slicedPoint(k).P1`, then this is the next segment. Sometimes, the next segment is stored as inverted segment as when `slicedPoint(i).P2 = slicedPoint(k).P2`. Point in `k` index will be swapped between `P1` to `P2` to fix the inverted segment. This algorithm works, but after several iterations, the search algorithm could not find next segment anymore even when I manually go through the remaining segments, I am able to locate the next segment. Here's the output:

```
DefaultSource Information: 0 : Intersecting Facet: 104
DefaultSource Information: 0 : Slicing Point: 104
DefaultSource Information: 0 : SliceZ: 1
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 0 0 (-57.1428571428571, -10) (-50, -10)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 1 0 (-50, -10) (-49.7306428571429, -9.49302657142857)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 2 0 (-49.7306428571429, -9.49302657142857) (-49.68575, -9.408531)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 3 0 (-49.68575, -9.408531) (-49.3656414285714, -8.93196814285714)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 4 0 (-49.3656414285714, -8.93196814285714) (-49.31229, -8.852541)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 5 0 (-49.31229, -8.852541) (-48.94485, -8.41144757142857)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 6 0 (-48.94485, -8.41144757142857) (-48.88361, -8.337932)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 7 0 (-48.88361, -8.337932) (-48.47273, -7.93699142857143)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 8 0 (-48.47273, -7.93699142857143) (-48.40425, -7.870168)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 9 0 (-48.40425, -7.870168) (-47.9542928571429, -7.51363771428571)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 10 0 (-47.9542928571429, -7.51363771428571) (-47.8793, -7.454216)
```

it works well, until:

```
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 22 0 (-44.2059442857143, -6.25492957142857) (-44.11039, -6.25)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 23 0 (-44.11039, -6.25) (31.5074214285714, -6.25)
DefaultSource Information: 0 : Not Found
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 24 0 (-49.6323985714286, 9.32910385714286) (-49.31229, 8.852541)
```

but the 24th actual pair P2 `(31.5074214285714, -6.25)` can be located at 67

```
DefaultSource Information: 0 : 67 0 (44.11039, -6.25) (31.5074214285714, -6.25)
```

which fulfills the statements when `slicedPoint(i).P2 = slicedPoint(k).P2`
This is rather confusing. Is there an error in my coding? or this is just a bad approach in handling array of struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved. I simply changed `Vector2d` format to `Vector2` which uses `Single`-type instead of `Double`, and the algorithm works. Apparently VB is unable to handle too much Double which is 64 bits precision probably due to memory issue. Perhaps someone could explain this better.